# iframe not scrollable in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

iam developing cordova app i just view iframe in that app but i have a problem that the iframe is not scrollable on ios could anyone help me

```css
.mainFrame{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-width:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
  <div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
     <iframe class="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" src="http://demo.demo.com" ></iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i replaced iframe with 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 .mainFrame {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border-width:0px;
        overflow:scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
    }
     <iframe class="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" src="http://demo.demo.com" ></iframe>
```

OR check this [tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios) it's work for me